# After a few successful urlopen(s), start getting 403

Tags: python

I have a list of URLs for Digikey product pages.  The goal is to open each URL then scrape pricing info and create a BoM.

The challenge I am having is that after opening a few URLs, URLError starts occurring with 403 (Forbidden) - even though I can open these URLs in my (Chrome) browser (on Mac).

What reasons could there be to go from opening each URL to deciding my opening a URL is forbidden within the Python script?  Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request, URLError
urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=RC0805JR-071KL',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=08055C333KAT2A',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=B72660M0251K072',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=HI1206T500R-10',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=LVR005NK-2',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=RL1220S-120-F',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=RMCF0805JT330R',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=IND-LED',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=CHV1206-JW-224ELF',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=RAC03-3.3SGA',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=202R18W102KV4E',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=GRM32DR72H104KW10L',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=CRE1S0505S3C',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=SJ-3523-SMT-TR',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=ATM90E26-YU-RCT-ND',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=CL21F104ZBCNNNC',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=CL21A106KQCLRNC',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=535-9865-1-ND',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=c',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=CL21C180JBANNNC',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=BLM15AG100SN1D',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=RMCF0805JT51R0',
'https://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=SI8651BB-B-IS1']
#####################################
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    try:
        with urlopen(url) as response:
            html = response.read()
            print (html)
        print("DONE WITH THIS URL.")
    except URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

Comment: Maybe the webserver does not like to be scraped and blocks you as soon as it notices what you are doing? Are you sure you are allowed what you are doing?

Comment: [Digikey's robots.txt](http://www.digikey.com/robots.txt) signals pretty clearly that they don't want bots scraping their catalog data. (Edit: At least, they've specifically disallowed /scripts/. You may try going directly to a product's /product-detail/ page.)

Comment: Thank you. Your advice helped me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, indeed digikey was assuming my code was a bot.  The "workaround" included:

- not using scripts in the URL
- randomly selecting a different user agent if get a http 403.

Thank you.